# F# Short Circuit Pattern Matching

Tags: .net, visual-studio, f#, functional-programming

New to F#. The following question may make no sense at all.

```
// an attempt at Huffman encoder 
let encodeValue x y = function ...

match ((encodeValue left value), (encodeValue right value)) with
    | ((true, encoded), (_, _)) -> (true, encoded + "1")
    | ((_, _), (true, encoded)) -> (true, encoded + "0")
    | ((false, _), (false, _)) -> (false, "")
    | _ -> failwith "Error"
```

In a real environment, encodeValue may be quite expensive. Is it possible (or reasonable) to ask F# to evaluate `encodeValue left value` first, attempt matches, and then execute `encodeValue right value` when necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can emulate short-circuiting nicely with lazy values and active patterns:

```
//not sure why function Lazy.force is recognized in VS but not in FSI
//need to use member Force()
let (|Force|) (l:Lazy<_>) =
    l.Force()

let encodeValue x y = function ...

match (encodeValue left value), lazy(encodeValue right value) with
    | (true, encoded), _                    -> (true, encoded + "1")
    | _              , Force(true, encoded) -> (true, encoded + "0")
    | (false, _)     , Force(false, _)      -> (false, "")
    | _                                     -> failwith "Error"
```

`Lazy` values are calculated 0 or 1 times: if you never call `Force()` on them they will never be calculated. The first time you call `Force()` they are calculated and the result saved for every other time you call `Force()`.

`(|Force|)` here is a complete active pattern, a really neat feature which allows you to implement custom pattern match structures of sorts.

Notice as @Brian pointed out that you need to use `_` in the lazy value position where short-circuiting is possible. If `(true, encoded)` matches then the lazy, expensive calculation is never forced. Then for each other case multiple matches using the `(|Force|)` active pattern will only use the result from the first incident.

**Update**

@Daniel pointed out that F# already has an active pattern that does exactly what `(|Force|)` does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340223.aspx

Comment: I think you need to change `Force(_,_)` to `_` on the first line?

Comment: Lazy.force is in the power pack (https://github.com/fsharp/powerpack/blob/master/src/FSharp.PowerPack.Compatibility/lazy.fs), so you need #r the "FSharp.PowerPack.Compatibility".

Comment: @Stephen: [Such an active pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340223.aspx) is built-in.

Comment: @Daniel: ha! never noticed that one

Answer (score 3):

The active pattern solution is way cooler but I thought it would at least be worth mentioning that a simple nested match will also look quite passable here:

```
  match encodeValue left value with
    | true, e -> true, e + "1"
    | false, _ -> 
      match encodeValue right value with
        | true, f -> true, f + "0"
        | _ -> false, ""
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another active pattern solution. Pass the partially-applied function to the active pattern:

```
let (|Encoded|_|) f x = 
  match f x with
  | true, encoded -> Some encoded
  | _ -> None

match value with
  | Encoded (encodeValue left) encoded -> (true, encoded + "1")
  | Encoded (encodeValue right) encoded -> (true, encoded + "0")
  | _ -> (false, "")
```

I dropped the last pattern because it will never match.

Answer (score 1):

As F# is not lazy functional language (you can make expressions evaluation lazy explicitly though).
What you can do is break down the pattern matching as shown below.

```
let a() = match encodeValue left value with
          | (true,encoded) -> (true,encoded + "1")
          | _ -> (false,"")
let b() = match encodeValue right value with
          | (true,encoded) -> (true,encoded + "0")
          | _ -> (false,"")
match a() with
| (false,_) -> b()
| r -> r
```